Equation of motion for particle in the gravitational field: does the solution contain a singularity at the limit $\vec{r}\to 0$
$\def\norm#1{\lVert #1 \rVert}$Assume that a particle of mass $m$ is in the gravitational field of a mass $M\gg m$. To simplify the problem we model the body with mass $M$ as a point mass at the origin; we use a two-dimensional coordinate system. If $\vec {r}$ is the position vector of the particle the equation of motion is
$$
\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}=-GM \frac{\vec{r}}{\norm{\vec{r}}^3}.
$$
At time $t=0$, $\vec{r}=(0,h)$ and $d\vec{r}/dt=(-v_0,0)$.
I am not interested in a general solution to this equation. I am trying to understand the behaviour of the solution as $\norm{\vec{r}}\to 0$. Do we reach a singularity where $\lim_{t\to\infty}\vec{r}=(0,0)$ (particle gets stuck at the origin) or will the acceleration produced by the infinite force near the origin propel the particle to the other side of the galaxy?
I have added some numerical solutions for different values of $G$ given $v_0$ and $h$.


Numerical solutions, particularly those corresponding to a fixed time step, require special care in the cases of highly eccentric orbits. Your plots show a typical spurious precession, an artifact of an inaccurate numerical integration of the equations of motion.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 yes it is possible that two of the orbits are an artifact of a combination of the time step (I am using $10^{-5}$ sec) and the approximation used for the second derivative. This figure is intended as an illustration that none of the orbits (even the spurious ones) collapse to a singularity.

I have corrected my answer. It contained a wrong statement.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 thanks for this comment. The graph (bar the two spurious trajectories) shows that your prediction is correct.

The particle's motion must satisfy the conservation of energy (the force is conservative) and angular momentum (it is a central force).
In connection with the given initial position and velocity, such conditions imply that with an initial position with a non-zero $h$, the particle can pass through the origin only in the very special case of $v_0=0$. For all non-zero initial velocity values, the trajectory cannot pass through the origin (it would imply a violation of the angular momentum conservation).
Although the force, acceleration, and velocity become singular when the particle passes through the origin, energy conservation allows us to exclude both scenarios: a particle stuck at the origin or sent to infinity. We can work with the well-behaving motion with initial conditions $h\neq 0$ and $v_0 \rightarrow 0$. The trajectory is an ellipse degenerating into a segment from $(0,h)$ to $(0,-h)$.
Errata:
The sentence in italics is wrong. By decreasing the non-zero initial velocity in the x-direction, the trajectories are ellipses with increasing eccentricity, with a common focus in $(0,0)$. Thus, the highly singular limit of the orbit will be a degenerate ellipse corresponding to a segment from $(0,h)$ to $(0,0)$. Such an orbit is highly singular, although it corresponds to the limit of regular orbits. It would contain a sudden velocity jump from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$. However, from the physical point of view, such a limit is meaningless. At short distances, the extended nature of gravitating bodies plays a role, and strictly pointlike gravitating bodies don't exist.

Thanks for this very helpful answer which underlines a very crucial point that I completely missed. Allow me some time to consider it. I have added some numerical simulations to the original question that support your point.

Yes, you reach a singularity as r approaches zero. However, a singularity doesn't mean that the particle gets stuck at the origin. It means that the math fails at that point. The particle getting stuck would be a definite solution. The singularity means that there is no defined solution.
Here, there is no defined solution because division by 0 is undefined.
Note, this situation only happens for a particle with 0 angular momentum. Otherwise it will not reach the singularity.

Thanks for your quick response. However, I would appreciate a bit more mathematical detail.

@TedBlack I added a sentence of detail. I feel like that may not be enough, but I am not sure how else to say it. Division by zero is undefined.

I would put it “a particle with zero angular momentum (i.e. not orbiting) will eventually reach the singularity at $r=0$ so there is no solution for a non-orbiting particle, since such a solution would include a point where you need to take divsion by zero”. +1, Dale.
